# Unix domain socket file not removed on application crash

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, unix-socket

I have a Linux C++ application which spawns and interact with another process through Unix Domain Socket. This new process basically just displays an icon of the process being currently runnning in the taskbar with some menu items displayed in the icon.

Problem: 
When main application is closed gracefully the UDS file is removed.
But in case of an application crash, this UDS file is not removed and it lingers.

Is there any way of removing the UDS file upon application crash through coding?

Comment: 1. signal handler, 2. write better code that doesn't crash.

Comment: Richard Hodges: Signal handler will not catch application crash or SIGKILL

Comment: Any reason you spammed the tag for the unrelateded language C on a clear C++ question?

Comment: @saras_ankit in which case, you're stuck with writing code that does not crash. Check your error conditions, throw exceptions on errors and use RAII to auto-close the socket and delete the file! c++ 101.

Comment: @Olaf I do not C tag being used in the question

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks for the suggestion. I am already passing the child process the control to kill itself when parent has died using prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM) and kernel takes care of closing the socket, but the problem is the UDS file still lingers.

Comment: @saras_ankit The edit history tells different! Don't lie so obviously.

Comment: @Olaf sorry my mistake

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way of removing the UDS file upon application crash through coding?

Yes. Several ways depending on how okay you are with using potentially non portable capabilities or not.

**Using a separate process:**

Use a separate process to monitor your application; perhaps one you've written for this purpose. When this monitoring process detects that your application has ended, it checks for the Unix domain socket file. If found, it deletes it. It then restarts the application (if needed).

**Using "abstract socket":**

I believe you can also use an "abstract socket", though I have not tried this myself.

An online [linux manual page for the Unix domain socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) describes an extension called "abstract sockets". It explains that: "Abstract sockets automatically disappear when all open references to the socket are closed.".

**Using "close-behind semantics":**

A Linux-based [Unix domain socket manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) notes section claims: "The usual UNIX close-behind semantics apply; the socket can be unlinked at any time and will be finally removed from the filesystem when the last reference to it is closed". I.e. call `bind` to create the socket, wait till the client has connected, then `unlink` the socket, then go about with the code that might crash. Once the socket is removed from the directory entry however, new client connection attempts will fail.

**Using a potential workaround**

Use `SO_REUSEADDR` on your socket before your `bind` call. This may allow the application to restart without needing to delete the socket. I do not know if this behavior is well defined though for Unix sockets. It may work on one platform but not another.

> Problem: When main application is closed gracefully the UDS file is removed. But in case of an application crash, this UDS file is not removed and it lingers.

Another way to handle the Unix domain socket file (the portable/standard version of it) is to delete the socket file in your application before it goes about creating it. So before your application calls `bind`, it would use `unlink`. So long as it's the sole process that would be creating this file, things should be copacetic w.r.t. avoiding races.

Beware though that using `unlink` could open a potential security vulnerability if your application runs with heightened privileges (for instance using the set-user-ID capability to run as say root). Make sure then that the user cannot tell the application what path to use for the socket and that none of the directories wherein the socket will reside is modifiable by the user. Otherwise, a user could tell the application that the socket's full path was something like `/etc/passwd` and run it to have that file deleted even though the user them self would not have had the privilege to do it.

This potential for damage is of course mitigated by things like using a least-privileged account for a set-user-ID privilege or by avoiding set-user-ID all together. Another mitigation would be to not allow the user to instruct the application what path to use for its socket - like perhaps by just using a hard-coded pathname for which the user would have no write privileges to any of its directories.

Comment: hi, where can I find the socket file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps, but you can detect and orphaned unix socket.

You can try locking a file or the socket on start-up. If the lock succeeds that means the socket is orphaned and can be removed. This is because file locks are released by the OS when a process is terminated for any reason.

Alternatively, `bind` to that unix socket. `bind` succeeds only if the socket name is unused.

Comment: "Alternatively, bind to that unix socket. bind succeeds only if the socket name is unused" - the problem is, that it fails if the socket name exists but is stale (i.e. is left over from a dead/crashed process). You can't use it to tell whether the socket is live. The only way to do that is to try and connect to it, but that's racy.